# Utility to convert satellite assembly to .resource file

Tags: .net, resources

Is there any utility available which does the inverse job as the al.exe ?

i.e converts a **Myresource.resources.dll  ---> Myresource.resources** file ??

Regards
Srivatsa

Answer (score 1):

[.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) can do this. Open the Myresource.resources.dll file, browse to Resources / Myresource.resources and select "Save as..." from the context menu.